# floating form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have created a regular form using html. Now I need to display that form using a link with floating window.(ex: floating feedback forms). In right side of website a button will appear, on moving cursor on that button, it will cause the form to float from **right side**. I have searched many websites but they have only left side option. please share a correct tutorial link or coding link.

Comment: "hovering mouse cursor on that button it floating that form" - please consider re-reading your question and making it more clear.

Comment: what did u see till now and please consider making your question more clear thank you

Answer (score 0):

Heres a tutorial that might help: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

Just change

```
tabLocation: 'left',
```

to

```
tabLocation: 'right',
```

and

```
action: 'click',
```

to

```
action: 'hover',
```

Comment: Thanks ya. it will float right to left correctly. but a big gap(space) is come inbetween image and content div. i'm trying to change various proberties in css and javascript. but not able to remove that space. what changes i do that?

Comment: No idea, you would have to show your code so I can reproduce the error